# compareTo method needs some work

Tags: java

I need to sort cities and states into an arraylist in alphabetical order of cities, but if 2 cities have the same name the state will be the tiebreaker.

```
public class City implements Comparable  
{
   String name;
   String state;

   /**
   ** A constructor for the city and state.
   ** @param name the name of the city.
   ** @param state the name of the state.
   */   
   public City(String name, String state)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.state = state;
   }
   //Gets the name and returns it.
   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }
   //Gets the state and returns it.
   public String getState()
   {
      return state;
   } 
   public int compareTo(Object otherCity)
   {
      City other = (City) otherCity;
      if (name.equals(other.name))
      {

      return name.compareTo(other.name);  
   }      
   public String toString()
   {
      return getClass().getName() + "[Name: " + name 
         + ", State: " + state + "]\n";
   }
}
```

This is the portion of code I believe is where I should make the condition for the tiebreaker but i'm not sure how to code it.

```
public int compareTo(Object otherCity) {
   City other = (City) otherCity;
   if (name.equals(other.name)){

     return name.compareTo(other.name);  
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: you are missing closing } in your compareTo method

Comment: You can use Arrays.sort method with custom comparator

Comment: You should probably type-bound your `Comparable` to `City` (so it'd read `Comparable<City>`.

Comment: I know the } is missing. I was actually stuck on how to code the tiebreaker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparable is generic, so I suggest you supply your type by implementing `Comparable<City>`

```
class City implements Comparable<City>
```

Then you can implement your comparison(s) with something like

```
@Override
public int compareTo(City other) {
    int r = this.name.compareTo(other.name);
    if (r != 0) {
        return r;
    } // the names are not the same, compare the states
    return this.state.compareTo(other.state);
}
```

or using the [ternary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

```
public int compareTo(City other) {
    int r = this.name.compareTo(other.name);
    // if (r != 0) then the names are not the same, compare the states
    return (r != 0) ? r : this.state.compareTo(other.state);
}
```

Also, since your fields do not have setters I suggest you mark them final so they are immutable

```
final String name;
final String state;
```

Comment: +1 for the use of generics here. Also note that this code assumes that the "name" and "state" fields are never null, so that should be enforced somewhere (for example the constructor could check for nulls and assign empty strings to the fields instead.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm going to assume you went along with my suggestion in the comments and type-bound your `Comparable`.)

If the city name is equivalent, then the state is the tie-breaker.  That's straightforward:

```
public int compareTo(@Nullable City otherCity) {
    if(null == otherCity) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(name.compareTo(otherCity.getName() == 0) {
        return state.compareTo(otherCity.getState());
    } else {
        return name.compareTo(otherCity.getName());
    }
}
```

There's an optimization in there in that you don't have to make two calls to `getName`, but this should give you the general idea.  Further, you have setters/getters; your fields should be `private`.

Comment: Thank you! I changed those field to private.

Answer (score 2):

You can tryout this. Here I consider the state value if two cities are equal.

```
public int compareTo(Object otherCity){
    City other = (City) otherCity;
    int iReturn = name.compareTo(other.name);
    if (iReturn == 0){
         //use your logic what to do when strings are equal. e.g.
         iReturn = iReturn = state.compareTo(other.state);
    }
    return iReturn;  
}
```